# RESTful ws with form parameters in Angularjs using $resource

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone explain how can i make a post request with some values in the body of the request in Angularjs?

I tried this solution:

```
'getNomeServizio': 
   { method: "POST", 
     url: basePath, 
     headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
   }
```

In my controller:

```
(new Service()).$getNomeServizio(
    $.param({chiave1: valore1, chiave2: valore2'})
).then(function (data) {
      ...
}, function (error) {
      ....
})
```

I want to use $resource but the request doesn't pass form-parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you only want $resource or looking another rest options as well

Comment: If possible I would prefer to use $ resource..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Service.getNomeServizio({chiave1: 'valore1', chiave2: 'valore2'}, function(){
  //success
}, function(){
  //error
})
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but the values ​​are passed as query parameters and not as form parameters..